# TS(7015) Element implicitly has an any type because index expression is not of type number

Tags: typescript

Im getting this compilation error in my Typescript code :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.typescript(7015)

```
export class OntologyFunctions {

    // function to clear selected properties
    @OntologyEditFunction()
    public async cancelmanualrc(
        missingpart: OanalyticsMissingPartsRca[],
        propertiesToClear: string[]
    ): Promise<void> {

        var x = "";
        var key_aligned;
        for (const key of propertiesToClear) {

            key_aligned = COLUMN_MISSING_PART_REMPLACE[key as typeof x];
            
            missingpart[key_aligned as keyof ObjectPartsNew] = undefined;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To index an array your key has to be a number not a string.

On this line:

```
key_aligned = COLUMN_MISSING_PART_REMPLACE[key as typeof x];
```

It looks like `COLUMN_MISSING_PART_REMPLACE` is an array and `key` is a string since `propertiesToClear` was declared as a `string[]` (This means you also don't need to recast it to a string too)

Comment: Hello I define COLUMN_MISSING_PART_REMPLACE as


`const COLUMN_MISSING_PART_REMPLACE: {[key: string]: string} = {
            "Manual RC" : "manual_rc_description",
            "Responsible Manual" : "manual_responsability",
        }`

Comment: Please can I define as string ?? @Joel Lefkowitz

Comment: Then it looks like `key_aligned` is a string and `missingpart` is an array since it's defined as `OanalyticsMissingPartsRca[]` and so it cannot be indexed with a string. Did you mean to use an object instead?

Comment: Yes, I mean to use an object.  @Joel Lefkowitz

Comment: yes I mean to use an object and I want to clear selected properties. Can you help me ?

Comment: Change the type of `OanalyticsMissingPartsRca[]`. For example if its a map of strings to strings then its `Record<string, string>`. If its values can be strings or numbers then use `Record<string, string | number>` etc 
,